# iOS developer working with Android Agency team, image viewing issues

Tags: android

I'm an indy iOS programmer, now working with a NYC agency on the Android Port of an App we shipped to the Apple Store. We have some image viewing issues on Android. Images that look great on the iPhone, are a bit blurry on Android, the Android group says this has to do with:

Their words:
"it.sephiroth.android.library.imagezoom, and that's the problem."

It corrupts the image. So now my client is about to get a bill from the Agency team to rebuild the image viewing piece from scratch on Android, just wondering if that's a know issue with Android (image viewing issues) and what are some tips from the Android community on best practices for displaying high resolution images on the Android platform.

I'm an iOS guy, willing to learn! Yes, I know it's a broad question, and I have no code samples here, just need to know what I should be Google'ing for. Then can post relevant blocks of code.

Or should this be an issue at all?

Thanks :-)

Comment: What app are you porting and which company?

Comment: If they get it working, I'll update on the solution. thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this question is pretty vague and there aren't any code snippets, I'll give you a starting point. It sounds like you're using this widget:

https://github.com/sephiroth74/ImageViewZoom

The first thing you'll want to ensure is that you have the latest version of this widget. If not, update it!

Edit: Looks like this project hasn't been updated for a while, so this is likely not the problem.